# How to record shell interaction from a background script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, background-process

I want to write a background sh (it can be python or any other language actually) script very much like `script`.

Its main purpose is to run on the background after invoked and listen to inputs (not the outputs nor the PS1 shell prompt string nor keystrokes like "End", "Ctrl", arrow-keys, etc.) that the user enters to the shell from which the script was originally invoked and then record them.

The dumbest approach would use `script` and then try to subtract PS1 and outputs from the generated file. But this would be error-prone and there sure are better ways to do this.

I've read about [pam_tty_audit](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-configuring_pam_for_auditing) but I'm not sure if one can easily filter out just the user input and I'm afraid it won't work for all Linux distributions.

What else can I look into to accomplish that?

A quick example illustrating what I seek:

The user would input this to the shell:

```
$ ./myscript
MyScript started in the background
$ echo "foo"
$ sudo apt install netcat
[sudo] password for user: MYPASSWORD
...
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] NO
...
$ exit
MyScript exited
```

And my script would render this output file:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "echo \"foo\""
echo "NO" | echo "MYPASSWORD" | eval "sudo apt install netcat"
```

Obs.: Capturing the password typed for `sudo` is not really something I would like to perform, the above example is just the first which came to mind.

Comment: Is this about all shell interaction or also interaction through the TTY with programs that ask `y/n` questions etc?

Comment: @Corion it would be great if I would be capable of getting all shell interaction. Like interactions made within vim on that TTY. But just getting direct interactions with the prompt like `y/n` answers and issued commands is what is essential to me.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to reinvent `autoexpect` with some fairly naive assumptions about what it really takes and how human-readable and reusable the results could be.

Comment: @tripleee Didn't know about `autoexpect`. I'm open to make use of it within my script but it has to be able to capture interactions with multiple programs until `exit` is issued. But interfering with the shell prompt to prepend the `autoexpect` command to the user's input doesn't seem doable without an interactive shell.

Comment: You would run it sort of like `script`; but be prepared that the output is an `expect` script which probably won't be human-editable.

Comment: `echo "NO" | echo "MYPASSWORD" | eval  ...` doesn't do what I think you think it does.